# How do you create a text popup box in C?

Tags: c, windows, popupwindow

I want to make a popup that requires you to type something in and hit ok. Below is what I have so far:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, "Message", "Title", MB_OK);
```

It pops up a box, but you can't type anything in. Is there a way to popup a box that lets the user type something in before closing the popup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You may want to read about [Edit Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

What you're looking for is basically an edit control with the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style or alternatively some kind of top-level window with an edit control as a child.

For more information, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) .